Find highest (uphill) side of the road in QGIS
In QGIS, I have a GeoPackage polygon layer representing proposed roads and a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) of the existing terrain.
My goal is to find the uphill side of the roads so I can automate the design of the draining ditch system.
I tried segmenting the roads using transects, attributing an unique id for each transect and comparing opposite sides using dem sampled z values, but this approach fall short, especially when it comes to junctions on the roads.
I'm attaching an image of what is my ultimate goal with this question. I have a road network that I'm proposing for a project. the lines with arrows represent the draining ditches that i previously calculated with a model. However, I had to manually remove the ones on the downhill side of the road. My original question intended to find a solution to add to my model so i can filter out the stretched of ditch that are located on the downhill side of the road polygons.
Any tips or clues?

Do you want the output to be "left" or "right" based on the direction of the line segment?

Start with stream delineation. Set intersection (road, stream) cells of your DEM to Null. Culverts will start at these points. Raise road cells as another modification of dem. Repeat stream delineation.  Drains will run along the roads towards Null - sink cells

Use streams that are 'big' enough at 1st step

I'd compute the aspect from the DEM and sample that at points along the lines. Then compare the line direction at the point with the aspect direction. But without a clear output description I can't really go further. Does OP want a line network similar to the original but "uphill" 2m from the centrelines (ie where the drains will go)? Or just an indication of which side of the road network?

You had a tag for Python but have not presented any code so I removed it.



Single sided buffer both sides. I buffer with 40 m distance. To create two polygon layers, one for each side.

Field calculate the column side on both layer, value Left on the left buffer and Right on the right buffer.

Merge them.




Zonal statistics with statistics to calculate Mean to calculate the mean height value of each side.

Extract by expression: "_mean"=maximum(expression:="_mean", group_by:="road_id"). Replace road_id with the name of your unique road identifyer column. This will extract the buffer side with the heighest mean elevation.

Join the side attribute back to the road line layer.


Output is your line layer with the side attribute of which side is uphill:


Is this going to get confused if a single LINESTRING feature crosses the DEM such that the upper slope side changes? OP may want to segment their line network into small chunks first.

Yes I also thought about splitting the line into segments.
